# share a workspace on Accurev

Tags: workspace, accurev

I am new to Accurev. I am working on a workspace and I see a problem which I need help from a team member to look at the issue. what is the easiest way to let the other team member to access my files in my workspace through Accurev?

Using Subversion, anyone could checkout my branch and see my changes, build the code and reproduce the issue., But with Accurev I am not sure how to do the same.

Reading the Accurev documents, it looks like a workspace acts as a stream but cannot be shared between developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a few months since I've used Accurev, but if I recall correctly, your team members can browse your workspace.  If you're browsing your available streams using the GUI tool, there should be a setting at the bottom to show workspaces from all users.  This will allow them to at least browse your workspace.  If you want other developers to be able to change these files, you'll have to push them up into a stream.  If necessary, you can always create a new stream and re-parent your workspace.

Answer (score 3):

If you have kept any files in your workspace, another user can look at the "Version Browser" of that element in their workspace and see your kept version and look at your changes.

Or, you could create a new stream, reparent your workspace to this stream and promote your changes into  the stream.